# What are things to keep in mind while using Shared Preferences android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on a simple android application.

The application has the functionality of user login which is connected to php.

I am successful in getting login functionality done well. What I want now is to `save the username` so that I can `use it anywhere and anytime in my application`. After going through some SO threads I came to know that this is doable using android sharedPreferences.

But prior to implementing them I want to know some stuff that I should keep in mind while using `sharedPreferences` like

- what is basic task of shared preferences?
- what things to keep in mind while actually using them?
- what is proper way to programatically implement them in code?
- and finally how to remove them after they are used?

Comment: your questions are just very badly formatted. Please use I, instead of i. Please use `  - `, instead of your own bullets. Please stop the use of `...`, instead use `.`. Please use capital letters when you start a sentence.

Comment: @Siddharth:but why a down vote...u can suggest edits I will surely accept that...and the stuff is not regarding i or I viewer of the question might understand the theme...and there are worstly asked question but others do suggest edits instead of down voting them...

Comment: Your comment again has ...

Comment: @Siddharth:see the edits...

Comment: Vote down is important to get your attention. All your questions are badly formatted. All of them have common issues like I, bullets and that irritating ... We need to keep SO clean. And its important to share learning and rules.

Comment: @Siddharth : i have gone through FAQs but still can you suggest me some post regarding this.

Comment: No post to refer to, just simple grammar knowledge that we learn in school. I wonder why you looked for something in the FAQ that is taught in 2nd grade. Capital letters, nouns and I to be capital and . used for full stop not ... Enough of this, you get the point, I reversed the down vote, case closed. No more please. I dont have all day to sit and respond to each of your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **what is basic task of shared preferences?**

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) are essentially used when you need your application to store persistent data. I consider using it when a Database is (*for the sheer purposes of size / data to be stored*) isn't really required.

> **what things to keep in mind while actually using them?**

You can save *just about* anything that you typically require for your application to perform it's task. For example, in a gaming application, you could store the user's scores. However, since the `SharedPreferences` file/s can be accessed by anyone on a [**rooted**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting) device, you wouldn't want to store passwords. If you **absolutely must** store them anyway, you should implement your own algorithm to encrypt it. In an app of mine, I store URL's to a user's profile picture on Facebook and Twitter. That is already in the public domain.

> **what is proper way to programatically implement them in code?**

If you are going to use `SharedPreference` in say, just one or two Activities, you use something like this to add values to the SharedPreference file:

```
// THE SHAREDPREFERENCE INSTANCE
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

// THE EDITOR INSTANCE
Editor editor;

// A CONSTANT STRING TO PROVIDE A NAME TO THE SHAREDPREFERENCE FILE
private static final String PRIVATE_PREF = "some_file_name";

// INSTANTIATE THE SHAREDPREFERENCE INSTANCE
sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// INSTANTIATE THE EDITOR INSTANCE
editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

// ADD VALUES TO THE PREFERENCES FILE
editor.putLong(UNIQUE_KEY_NAME, VALUE);
editor.putString(UNIQUE_KEY_NAME, VALUE);
editor.putString(UNIQUE_KEY_NAME, VALUE);
editor.putString(UNIQUE_KEY_NAME, VALUE);

// THIS STEP IS VERY IMPORTANT. THIS ENSURES THAT THE VALUES ADDED TO THE FILE WILL ACTUALLY PERSIST
// COMMIT THE ABOVE DATA TO THE PREFERENCE FILE
editor.commit();
```

To fetch the values out of the file:

```
String someString = sharedPrefs.getString(UNIQUE_KEY_NAME, null);
long someLong = sharedPrefs.getLong(UNIQUE_KEY_NAME, 0);
```

If you need to reuse the contents / values from the `SharedPreference` file, this here is a nice tutorial on creating a helper class that will let any number of `Activites` to access the values instead of coding the above in every single one of them: http://megasnippets.com/source-codes/java/sharedpreferences_helper_class_android

> **and finally how to remove them after they are used?**

```
// INSTANTIATE THE EDITOR INSTANCE
editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

// TO CLEAR A SELECT FEW OF THE VALUES:
editor.remove(KEY_FOR_THE_VALUE_TO_BE_REMOVED);

// ALTERNATIVELY, TO CLEAR ALL VALUES IN THE FILE:
editor.clear();
```

**Note:** Any `SharedPreferences` file/s you may create will be removed when the user manually clears the app data from the device's Settings.

*Links For Further Reading:*

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html
2. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html
3. http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12260/android-sharedpreferences-example/
4. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 2):

### How to Save/Read 'username' from SharedPreferences Persistent Storage

**Basic Task**:

Persistent storage.

**Keep In Mind**:

Is there so much data that you might be better off using a database or flat file storage?

**Proper Way to Save and Read "username"**:

```
String key = "username";
String value = "John Doe";

// Save
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();

// Read
String def = "";
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!settings.contains(key)) {
    // Warn user that there is nothing to read and/or return a default value: "def"
}
String value = settings.getString(key, def);
```

Comment: persisting storage means?besides is it feasible to store retrieved

Comment: "Persistent" means that the value stays in storage always. Even after application stops running. Even after device powers off. Value stays in memory until it is erased or application is deleted from phone. It is the best way to save username and various flags to indicate that the user has been authenticated. Caution: password is not saved in a secure manner. Don't save it unless absolutely required.

Comment: where are they physically stored in phone or sdcard

Comment: Always stored in phone internal memory, in "sandbox" of app data for the specific application for which it is being used. Cannot use SC card because a) not secure, b) may not be there, c) can get changed by external means.

Answer (score 1):

**About the basic task** : 
you can read on [Storage Options at developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).
**About the keep in mind** : 
try to avoid saving sensetive data to your application in shared preferences,because user can easily access the data.
You can find your shared preferences xml file in **/data/data/your_application.package.name/shared_prefs/shared_prefs_name.xml**
**Implementation** :
Usualy I am creating class with static methods like this :

```
public class MySharedPreferences {

    private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "my_prefs";
    private static final String KEY_LOGIN = "username";

    public static void setUsername(Context context, String username) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, login);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUsername(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i remove the application specific shared preferences?any idea

Comment: What you mean to remove?For which purpose?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible,but you can find more information there : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html